# C: find the longest line

Tags: c

This is an example program from the book The C Programming Language by Dennis Ritchie and Brian Kernighan (Second Edition). My question is if we are passing the value(variable line) but not the reference to the function length, then how does the change reflect in the main function?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define MAXLINE 1000

int length(char s[], int lim);
void copy(char to[], char from[]);

int main() {
    int len;
    int max;
    char line[MAXLINE];
    char longest[MAXLINE];

    max = 0;
    while ((len = length(line, MAXLINE)) > 0) {
        if (len > max) {
            max = len;
            copy(longest, line);
        }
    }

    if (max > 0) {
        printf("%s", longest);
    }

    return 0;
}

int length(char s[], int lim) {
    int c, i;

    for (i = 0; i < lim - 1 && (c = getchar()) != EOF && c != '\n'; ++i) {
        s[i] = c;
    }

    if (c == '\n') {
        s[i] = c;
        ++i;
    }

    s[i] = '\0';
    return i;
}

void copy(char to[], char from []) {
    int i;

    i = 0;
    while ((to[i] = from[i]) != '\0') {
        ++i;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you rephrase your question?

Comment: I guess I know what you mean. We're passing `line` to `length`, and `length` modifies it. And then in `main` we see those changes made to `line`. Is that what's confusing you?

Comment: @user366312, in the while loop in main, we only get the length of the line. Also, we are passing the value of the variable line to the function length. But the function length only gets the line ( from stdin) and return the length of the line. So, my question is how can the main function still access the local variable (s[]) of the length function?

Comment: @bereal Yeah, you got it.

Comment: since the strings are passed by pointer, line in the main function and s in the length function are the same, only addressed with a different name. So you access the string (in length() with name s) in main by using _line_

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This definition:

```
int length(char s[], int lim)
```

can be rewritten as:

```
int length(char *s, int lim)
```

which might make it easier to understand. We don't pass the variable by value, we pass the pointer, so the function can access the data and modify it if necessary.

Comment: Oh, I didn't know that character arrays are not passes by value in C. Thank you for the answer.

Comment: @EpycZen oh, don't worry, there are a lot of things in C/C++ that neither you neither me know =)

Answer (score 1):

```
len = length(line, MAXLINE)
```

in C all arrays are passed by pointer. so the function `length` receives the pointer to first char oh the array `line` and it modifies this array

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'm new to C.